# Proof on probability theory

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $B_1,B_2,\dots$ be a measurable partition of $\Omega$, that is the $B_i$'s are all measurable, $\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}B_i=\Omega$ and $B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. Let $\xi$ be an integrable random variable. Let $\mathcal{A}=\sigma\{B_1,B_2,\dots,\}$.
I have already shown $\mathcal{A}=\left\{\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i;I\subset\Bbb{N}\right\}$.
Can anyone help me with the following:
Assume $P(B_i)>0$ for all $i$. Show that $$\Bbb{E}[\xi\mid\mathcal{A}]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\Bbb{E}[\xi\mid B_i]1_{B_i}$$
Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question, but no attempt shown, so I downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a random variable of the form $Y = \sum_i y_i 1_{B_i}$, with $y_i$ bounded. Then 
$Y$ is ${\cal A}$ measurable (and integrable).

If $Y$ is a version of the conditional expectation $E(\xi | {\cal A} )$, then we must have $\int_A Y dP = \int_A \xi dP$ for all $A \in {\cal A}$. Setting $A= B_i$ shows that if $Y$ has the above form, then $y_i P(B_i) = \int_{B_i} \xi dP = E(\xi ; B_i)$.

If we let $Y = \sum_i \frac{E(\xi ; B_i)}{P(B_i)} 1_{B_i}$, it is straightforward to check that $Y$ is a conditional expectation.

For a particular $i$, repeating the above with $\sigma(\{B_i\})$ shows that $Z_i=\frac{E(\xi ; B_i)}{P(B_i)} 1_{B_i}$ is a version of the conditional expectation $E(\xi |B_i )$, hence we have $Y = \sum_i Z_i 1_{B_i}$, and we can write $E(\xi | {\cal A} ) = \sum_i E(\xi | B_i ) 1_{B_i}$.

Answer (score 1):

Does $\sum_{i=1}^\infty E[\xi \mid B_i]1_{B_i}$ qualify as being the conditional expectation $E[\xi\mid\mathcal{A}]$? In other words,

1. Is it integrable?
2. Is it $\mathcal{A}$-measurable?
3. Is
   $$
   \int_A\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty E[\xi \mid B_i]1_{B_i}\right)\,\mathrm dP=\int_A\xi\,\mathrm dP
   $$
   for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$?

Now, show a little effort and try to solve it on your own. Let me know if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

- The random variables $E[\xi\mid\cal A]$ and $E[\xi\mid\sigma(B_i)]$ are well-defined.
- The RHS is also well defined because for a fixed $\omega$ at most one terms is not $0$.
- Fix $A\in\cal$, and compare $E[\xi\chi_A]$ with $E[\mbox{RHS}]$.

Answer (score 0):

$\xi = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \xi 1_{ B_i}$. So
$$ \mathbb E [ \xi \vert \mathcal A] = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mathbb E[ \xi 1_{ B_i} \vert \mathcal A] = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mathbb E[ \mathbb E [\xi \vert B_i] 1_{ B_i} \vert \mathcal A] = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mathbb E [\xi \vert B_i] 1_{ B_i}, $$
the last equality holds because $\sigma(B_i) \subset \mathcal A$.